# Trying to make a login script with web.py

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I'm trying to make a login script with web.py but i cant seem to figure it out!

I'm using MySQLdb for the database engine.

Here are the two approaches I have but neither seem to be working. if someone can help me it would be very much appreciated.

Method 1

```
class login():
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        d = i.username
        email = db.select('users', where='email')

        if d == email:
            return"Success!"
        else:
            return"Nahh"
```

Method 2

```
class login():
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        u = i.username
        p = i.password
        d = db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=i.username AND password=i.password")
        g = db.num_rows(d)
        if g == 1:
            return "Success!"
        if g != 1:
            return "Fail!"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm still new to Web.py and I know the first example doesn't really make sense... but its just a theory I had if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use MySQLdb directly, or through web.py's web.db wrapper?

If you use webpy's wrapper then you should read manual on [db.select](http://webpy.org/cookbook/select) and [db.query](http://webpy.org/cookbook/query).

Comment: I have actually figured this part out. My problem now is confirming that the input is in the database with the num_rows statement. I think MySQLdb has something called countrows am I right>

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to chime in since the demo code posted above has potential SQL injection problems. I know it's been awhile and you've probably fixed these by now though.

My code looks very similar to your second method:

```
class Login(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render_template('login/login.html')

    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
        try:
            username = data.username

            # All passwords are stored hashed!
            password = hashlib.sha224(data.password).hexdigest()

            result = db.select("users",
                   vars = dict(username=username, password=password),
                   what = 'id',
                   where = "username=$username and password=$password")
            if len(result) != 0:
                web.ctx.session.userid = result[0].id
                web.ctx.user = UserModel(result[0].id)
                return web.seeother('/')
        except Exception, e:
            return render_template('login/login.html',errors=["Bad user/pass"])
```

In production I actually have a few more keys in my vars dict, like is_active. I also log any exception. I'm using Jinja as the templating engine, which is why my responses are a little different from yours.